# How do I force a button response to say a text vs its label?

Tags: ios, voiceover, uiaccessibility

**Scenario:** User has 5 stars (buttons).  Each button has a UIAccessibility label to describe the star ("First Star of Five", etc.).

**Problem:** Upon selection, UIAccessibility repeats the label.   I want to change that to 'Selected' (or "You have selected the 2nd Star.").

[image]

**Attempted Solution:**

I tried to squash the button's action response and got silence; which is expected, I guess.

```
cell.button2.accessibilityLabel = @"Second star of Five.";
cell.button2.accessibilityTraits += UIAccessibilityTraitStartsMediaSession;
```

But I also don't want an automated repeat of the label.

 How can I have full control of 'Voice Over' upon selection of each star button so user understands the selection vs merely repeating the label?

---

Per suggestion below, I can't override the accessibilityLabel of my custom button class.  I have ObjC code, but prefer to work with Swift.   So I'm trying to incorporate the custom UIButton class written in Swift, into ObjC.

[image]

Comment: Only for the a11y purpose, is it necessary to have a dedicated button for each star OR is it conceivable to wrap all of them in a single object working like a slider only for VoiceOver to provide the desired rate? 

Answer (score 0):

Define a `CustomStarButton` and overwrite the `- (NSString *)accessibilityLabel{}` func, if selected, return @"You have selected the 2nd Star."

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested but can't override the accessibilityLabel.

Comment: `override class func accessibilityLabel() - String? {}`

Comment: Probably with SwiftUI but not with UIKit.

Comment: `open override var accessibilityLabel: String? { get{ if (isSelected ? "" : "") } set { accessibilityLabel = newValue } }`  I'm not familiar with Swift, maybe you can try this.

Comment: I believe I had tried something like this but the compiler complains.